# Unable to add elements to scala mutable list inside foreach loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, scala-collections

I am trying to add elements in a `mutable scala list` as below. I am reading the values from a dataframe row by row, extracting out values of column with name "_title" and adding it to list. But when for loop is complete, the list is still enmpty. this is the code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val flatK = dfR.withColumn("UserValue", explode(col("UserValue")))
var colListA = new ListBuffer[String]()
//    var colSet : List[String] = List()
    for(i <- 0 until Integer.parseInt(dfR.count().toString)){
      flatK.filter($"columnIndex" === i).foreach{
        r=>
          val columnName = r.getAs[Row]("UserValue").getAs[String]("_title")
//          println(columnName)
          colListA.append(columnName)
      }
    }
```

`println(columnName)` actually prints the value I want to put inside my list.
My dataframe `dfR` looks like this:

```
 +--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|UserValue                                                     |columnIndex|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|[, last_mod_date, 2009-01-14T13:40:53]                        |0          |
|[, object_string, SOLIDS]                                     |0          |
|[, last_mod_date, 2009-01-13T22:58:30]                        |1          |
|[, object_string, TORSO]                                      |1          |
```

When I do

```
colListA += "elements"
colListA += "adds"
```

I can see elements added. But not inside that `foreach` loop. Can any one tell me what shall I try? Basically, I expect colList to be populated with `last_mod_date` and `object_string`.

Comment: This has been asked a lot of times before, but I can not find the excellent duplicate people always use. Anyways, short answer: The `foreach` is not executed in the **driver** _(where your buffer exists)_ but on the **executors** _(all of them had a local a copy of the buffer)_. At the end, each copy was modified but the results are not synced with the driver, thus the main buffer stays empty. This common novice mistake is done because a poorly understanding of Sparks architecture. I would recommend you to read a little bit about how spark works and what are they use cases.

Comment: Cool. But how can I achieve the purpose that I want here? If its a duplicate, is it possible for you to direct me to that link?

Comment: As I said, I could not find the exact duplicate with has super clear answer, but you can easily find a lot of similar questions. Now, how can you do it may depend on your real use case. You may simple call `collect` in order to have all values in your driver _(which looks like what you want)_ - be warned that, if the `DF` is big, you may just blow your memory. Spark was intended for working with large amount of data that wont fit in one machine, but since you are already working in local mode, just for debugging then you are done.

Comment: well, my dataframe could be very large actually. So if I do collect, it might run out of memory as well. Let me try to figure something else out.

Comment: You are trying to add each string from a List to mutuable.ListBuffer. Please correct me?

Comment: no. i am trying to add to a mutable list from a rdd.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list from column of a dataframe 
`dataframe.select("_title").collect().map(_(0).asInstanceOf[String]).toList`

you can get the list of string of your column.